# Magento 2.3 :: Does checkout handles concurrent requests?

Tags: magento2.3

Magento version: 2.3.1

We do flash sale for a particular product on our website on fixed date and time.

The product quantity is limited.

A lot of customers try to purchase the product at the same time.

We end up overselling the product.

My suspicion is Magento do not handle thread safety and thus concurrent requests are allowed to purchase the product.

For example, last quantity is remaining and two requests were received at the same time (this is a normal scenario in flash sales).

Then, will the method: $stockItem->getIsInStock() return true for both?

Comment: why don't you debug it by yourselft?
[xdebug](https://xdebug.org/wizard)

Answer (score 0):

By its very nature MySQL is transactional. So basically one order should start as another finishes and it's a first come first serve basis. That's why you see deadlocks. Rows or fields get locked whilst they are updated. Excessive extensions, inferior payment extension and underpowered instances and/or webserver could cause this.

I think you need to post more details? How many concurrent users do you get on a flash sale?